# MongoDB is much slower in comparision to MySQL - basic find() method

Tags: mysql, node.js, mongodb

It is my first Stackoverflow question but I'm long time reader.

I'm working on some home project and I tried to compare the speed of MongoDB and MySQL. Suprisingly.. MongoDB is almost 5 times slower even with very basic table? I was reading that they are almost the same speed but it got me thinking.

Can someone explain to me why is this happening?

The MongoDB code:

```
app.get('/mongodb', function(req, res, next) {
  var time = process.hrtime();
  User.find(function(err, users) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    var diff = process.hrtime(time);
    if(diff[0] == 0) {
      res.send(diff[1].toString());
    } else {
      res.send(diff[0]+"."+diff[1]);
    }
  });
});
```

The MySQL code:

```
app.get('/mysql', function(req, res, next) {
  var time = process.hrtime();
  mysql.query("SELECT * FROM users", function(err, results) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var diff = process.hrtime(time);
    if(diff[0] == 0) {
      res.send(diff[1].toString());
    } else {
      res.send(diff[0]+"."+diff[1]);
    }
  });
});
```

MySQL returns: 1.52201348

MongoDB returns: 9.746405351

Schema is:

```
User {
  id integer,
  name string,
  email string,
}
```

There are around 500000 of Users.

Index is on _id in MongoDB and id in MySQL.

MongoDB shell version: 2.4.6

MySQL version: 5.5.37

Any ideas? Any help or suggestions will be much appreciated.

Regards,
Wnzl.

Comment: MongoDB is not magic pixie dust you just sprinkle on a webapp for performance.

Comment: In addition, benchmarking is hard... There's a dozen questions to ask (for instance, is all the data accessed? How? What's the batch size? Is this a realistic use case?). Also, does mysql return strings or are these JSON objects already? Does that, under realistic circumstances, present any valid comparison? After all, the data model should be completely different. Because of all these questions, I consider this 'too broad'.

Comment: Hello.
I did not said it is easy, I know its hard thats why I stopped on simple "SELECT *". I'm also well aware that MySQL has different job than Mongo. But I want to compare the simplest possible scenario.

To answer at least few of your questions:
1) Can you explain something more about batch size and how to measure it? I've got default Mongo and Mysql running.
2) Yes, this is realistic use case. I want to select all users (possibly limit them by 50000) and work on the data I got.
3) MySQL returns json as well as Mongo.
4) The setup is Digital Ocean 4GB ram, 4 cpu setup.
5) Data is the same.

Comment: Every storage solution does one and the same thing at their very core, be it a relational db or a "NoSQL" like Mongo - they access the disk where the files are at. Now, the funny part with NoSQL is that they don't try to optimize the write process at all, since they let OS / HDD controller take care of that. MySQL on the other hand, implements so many optimizations from writing on the same disk sector to optimum flushes in a single I/O etc. So one problem is how the data is **retrieved** and the other problem is how it's **sent**. You need to measure both.

Comment: @ceejayoz I would say that is an inaccurate comment. On a straight table like this for MongoDB to perform 9x slower is...bad, very, very bad. MongoDB, on this query should be comparable to MySQL, they essentially do the same thing, nay MySQL actually does more since it has to IO write a result set whereas MongoDB reads directly from the data files

Comment: Sorry, read your comments. Hmm that setup should be good enough. Can you still upgrade to mongodb 3.0? And give us a mongostat output?

Comment: The batch size is set by default to be max it can, in other words if you have not changed it you cannot really optimise it. Essentially the batch size is: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.batchSize/

Comment: You might also be suffering from readahead settings on digital oceans servers: http://www.kchodorow.com/blog/2012/05/10/thursday-5-diagnosing-high-readahead/ but it is hard to say

Comment: Let's do some maths: we have 500k documents which **all** have to be read from disk *complety* since MongoDB itself knows *nothing* of a fixed schema. That's 0.00001949 and a bit seconds per document, which is 19.49 microseconds if I am not mistaken. Try to read 500k JSON files from disk with that average.

Comment: There isn't enough detail on the environment to understand what's being compared, and as other comments have noted Benchmarks Are Hard. There are a lot of variables that might affect performance, and to get a better understanding you'd need to compare with some server metrics as well (i.e. `mongostat`). Other Qs: What version of the MongoDB Node.js driver are you using? Are there any warnings similar to "Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version"? Also, are you running both MySQL & MongoDB on the same server? How many iterations of the test did you run to average your results?

Answer (score 1):

I think the main problem here is that benchmarking should always be done with respect to a special use case. 
The assumption, that they perfom with same speed is pretty unspecific.

So the use case you examine here is defined by your example and means getting all entities of a schema. Even if the use case is pretty simple,  the meaningfulness of your result won't be.

MongoDB and SQL are database systems designed for different use cases. This means that each system is optimized for different queries. This is where I think you should dig deeper to get the reason for different performances.

Also take into account, that based on hat, querying all entity's of one schema, perhaps could be realized with multiple but in total faster queries. Last think about bootstrap, caching and indexing mechanisms that may be  total different due to optimizations to system specific use cases.